Project Euler (18i): Remainder of $\prod_{x=0}^{p-1} (x^3 -3x +4)$ mod $p$
I'm stuck on this question too long, i'd like to get a clue or an idea for solution.
Let $R(p)$ be the remainder when the product $\prod_{x=0}^{p-1} (x^3 -3x +4)$ is divided by $p$.
For example $R(11)=0$ and  $R(29)=13$.
Find the sum of $R(p)$ over all primes $p$ between $10^9$ and $1.1*10^9$
I programmed for low primes, and saw almost exact $\frac{2}{3}$ of the primes the product is zero. I tried to get rid of some primes, by finding a shorter formula for $p$, checking for rational root of the polynom (which doesnt exist) or checking which primes have roots mod $p$ for the polynom , as described here:
How does Mathematica solve $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$? but it doesn't bring a solution for a general   prime p

Do you have a typo in the problem number? I can't find it on the site.

Which primes gave you a nonzero value?

@BrianMoehring $5, 13, 17, 29, 37, 61, 73, 89, 109, 113, 137, 149, 157, 173, 193, 197$, etc. OEIS is silent. All are $12k+1$ or $12k+5$. But e.g. $977$ is also $12k+5$ and is not present.

The fact that the polynomial has a root for $\frac23$ of the primes is a consequence of the Chebotarev density theorem. But that won't help here because there's not an easy pattern for which primes have roots.

@Amateur_Algebraist this question shows in "bonus" section (and called 18i, not a typo), and i just unlocked it. You may not have access to it.

Found something (we have $n=3$, $a=1$, $b=4$).

What is $18i$? The problems are all assigned numbers. Where do you see the "i"?

@Amateur_Algebraist Look under the "Bonus" section. It may be  locked for you

Doesn't Project Euler have a policy of prohibiting getting help from websites like this one?

Fix a prime $p > 3$. Denote $f(x) := x^3 - 3x + 4$ and $R = \prod_{t \in \mathbb{F}_p} f(t)$. We take two cases:

If the polynomial $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then it must have a zero in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Thus, $R = 0$.
Otherwise, if $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then its roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ must lie in $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}$. Observe that:
$$\prod_{t \in \mathbb{F}_p} f(t) = -\prod_{t\in \mathbb{F}_p}(\alpha-t)(\beta-t)(\gamma-t) = (\alpha^p-\alpha)(\beta^p-\beta)(\gamma^p-\gamma)$$
We know that $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\} = \{\alpha^p, \beta^p, \gamma^p\}$, so $R$ is equal to a square root of the discriminant of $f$. One can calculate this to be $-324$, so we get $R = 18i$ (hehe) for a square root $i$ of $-1$. This still leaves you with the task of figuring out which square root of $-1$ to pick.


Thanks! Seems like you got it!  Can u please explain what theorems you used in 1. f
is irreducible over Fp
, then its roots α,β,γ
must lie in Fp3, and the equalities in .2?

@meni This is field theory/galois theory of finite fields.  If you've not studied it before, there isn't really a super quick summary that can be given that will be comprehensible.  What do you know about finite fields?
